# Magento 2.2.8: How to solve the message “Unable to send email”?

Tags: error, send-mail, magento2.2.8

I have just installed magento 2.2.8 in XAMPP in local and run folllowing code but it throw error "unable to send mail"
then after When I changed password for customer,it throws same error
I executed php `mail()` function so This php works fine and it sending mail

```
 public function execute()
    {
        try {
              $sender = [
                'email' => "a@gmail.com",
                'name' => "aaaa"

            ];
            $sentToEmail = "bbbb@gmail.com";
            $sentToName = "bbbb";

            // $this->state->setAreaCode(Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
            echo "ddd";
            $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier(self::TEST_TEMPLATE_IDENTIFIER)
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => 1])
                ->setTemplateVars([])

               ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo($sentToEmail,$sentToName)
                ->getTransport()
                ->sendMessage();

           // print_r(__('Everything is fine, email has been sent.'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo "<pre>";print_r(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: reference link => https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180788/magento-2-how-to-solve-the-message-unable-to-send-email

Comment: php mail function works fine

Answer (score 1):

First check if your server's email is working. If its local system than you have to install SMTP module to send email.

check below code at root of magento by creating new file. and run url like: yourmagentobaseURL/yourfile.php

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";


$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: as per my question I mentioned that php mail() function works fine

Comment: please follow below link that kind of task I have done and fixed. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279330/magento-2-3-email-attachment-not-working-while-sending-custom-email